# Making external monitor of HP TouchScreen tx2 primary monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, touchscreen

I want to make an external monitor the primary monitor and the notebook monitor of the HP TouchScreen the secondary monitor on Windows Vista.
The usual way via preferences doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What graphics drivers are you using?

For ATI:

[image: Ati screen]

Change the "1" "2" buttons as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Vista, I only have Windows 7 on my Tx2, but when selecting the second monitor in the display options, there is a checkbox named "Make this my main display", and it works fine. You have to select the second monitor in order to see that checkbox.

Comment: Unfortunatly that box isn't clickable on my computer :(
Maybe I need Windows 7

Comment: Make sure that you have selected "Extend my desktop to this display" first and have applied the settings prior to switching primary monitors.